# Can't login mysql db access denied for user 'root'

Tags: permissions, login, mysql

after installing mysql-server using `sudo apt install mysql-server` and login by typing `mysql` `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'very_strong_password';`. After that I quit. And now when I'am trying to login mysql by typing `mysql` it tell me ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
I already tried

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

like commands and nothing changed. It's on my local computer and I'am using Ubuntu 20.04
I also tried to remove mysql and It also doesn't change anything
How can I login my mysql server.

Comment: Recent "best practice" for MySQL Server since 2017 has been to **not** use the `root` account unless setting the server up the first time or fixing something that has gone really, really wrong. You will likely need to remove MySQL, then remove the remaining files in `/var/lib/mysql` before you can have a system that works. **Note** that nothing should use the `root` account. Ever. Create a separate admin account with a good password. `root` is only for setup and fixing really big problems ...

Comment: If you set a password and want to use it, you must invoke the `mysql` command with the `-p` or `--password` option ex. `mysql -u root -p`